# Connect visual studio 2017 linux debugger from one laptop to ubuntu in another laptop

Tags: visual-studio, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed the Linux development in visual studio 2017 on my windows laptop. Usually, for debugging we have to connect with Azure VMs. I have Ubuntu on another laptop. Is it possible for me to connect vs 2017 Linux debugger with the Ubuntu on another laptop and run the programs? If so, then how.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of app are you building?

For .NET Core on Linux the instructions over at:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/debugging-net-core-on-unix-over-ssh/
For native there's instructions over at:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/targeting-windows-subsystem-for-linux-from-visual-studio/
It's for WSL but if you run those instructions on the Ubuntu box it should be the same.

In either case the key thing is that VS needs to be able to open an SSH tunnel to the Ubuntu laptop. That might mean changing around settings for firewalls either on the boxes or at the network layer.